# How to test my ios app using sandbox mode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-login

when i click login button it goes to safari and return back to my app and shows this message.

"This app is in sandbox mode.  Edit the app configuration at http://developers.facebook.com/apps to make the app publicly visible."

Comment: Follow the steps in this link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#prerequisites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have application in Facebook. There will be a option for Sandbox mode.[image]

If App is in Sandbox mode, You should be either Admin, Developer, Tester for that Application. Otherwise you should disable Sandbox mode.

Comment: but i cant able to login to facebook. once safari opens it automatically redirects to my app. no login screen appears.

Comment: For that only, i replied this answer. If you are a Admin or Developer or Tester only, you can login. Otherwise SandBox mode should be disabled. Are you using OpenGrpah?